# How Lord Brahma get back Vedas Which was Stolen by the Demons?

Tags: vishnu, vedas, brahma

As, I heard this incidence one of my vaisnav friend, Once the demons stole the four vedas from the lord brahma and by the help of Lord Vishnu, lord brahma got back the Vedas.
I am not sure about this incidence, But if you know about this incidence then kindly share, or Is there any scriptures which claimed that fact.then please share your idea.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This story is mentioned in Shanti Parva of [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c047.htm) when Madhu and Kaitabha the two daityas stolen Vedas from Lord Brahma. Then Brahma prayed to Lord Vishnu and then pleased by his prayers Vishnu takes Hayagriv form to restore the vedas. It is as follows:

> While engaged in thinking of Creation, he recollects his own high
>   attributes. From this springs the four-faced Brahma representing the
>   Consciousness of Anirudha. The illustrious Brahma, otherwise called
>   Hiranyagarbha, is the Grandsire of all the worlds. Endued with eyes
>   like lotus petals, he takes birth within the Lotus that springs from
>   (the navel of) Anirudha. Seated on that Lotus, the illustrious,
>   puissant, and eternal Brahma of wonderful aspect saw that the waters
>   were on all sides. Adopting the attribute of Sattwa Brahma, otherwise
>   called Parameshthi, then commenced to create the universe. In the
>   primeval Lotus that was endued with the effulgence of the Sun, two
>   drops of water had been cast by Narayana that were fraught with great
>   merit. The illustrious Narayana, without beginning and without end,
>   and transcending destruction, cast his eyes on those two drops of
>   water. One of those two drops of water, of very beautiful and bright
>   form, looked like a drop of honey. From that drop sprang, at the
>   command of Narayana, a Daitya of the name of Madhu made up of the
>   attribute of Tamas (Dullness). The other drop of water within the
>   Lotus was very hard. From it sprang the Daitya Kaitabha made up of the
>   attribute of Rajas. Endued thus with the attributes of Tamas and
>   Rajas, the two Daityas possessed of might and armed with maces,
>   immediately after their birth, began to rove within that vast primeval
>   Lotus. They beheld within it Brahma of immeasurable effulgence,
>   engaged in creating the four Vedas, each endued with the most
>   delightful form. **Those two foremost of Asuras, possessed of bodies,
>   beholding the four Vedas, suddenly seized them in the very sight of
>   their Creator. The two mighty Danavas, having seized the eternal
>   Vedas, quickly dived into the ocean of waters which they saw and
>   proceeded to its bottom.** Seeing the Vedas forcibly taken away from
>   him, Brahma became filled with grief. Robbed of the Vedas in this way,
>   Brahma then addressed the Supreme Lord.
>
> Thus praised by Brahma, the illustrious Purusha, with face turned towards every side, then shook off his slumber, resolved to recover
>   the Vedas (from the Daityas that had forcibly snatched them away).
>   Applying his Yoga-puissance, he assumed a second form. His body,
>   equipt with an excellent nose, became as bright as the Moon. He
>   assumed an equine head of great effulgence, which was the abode of the
>   Vedas. The firmament, with all its luminaries and constellations,
>   became the crown of his head. His locks of hair were long and flowing,
>   and had the splendour of the rays of the Sun. The regions above and
>   below became his two ears. The Earth became his forehead. The two
>   rivers Ganga and Saraswati became his two hips. The two oceans became
>   his two eye-brows. The Sun and the Moon became his two eyes. The
>   twilight became his nose. The syllable Om became his memory and
>   intelligence. The lightning became his tongue. The Soma-drinking
>   Pitris became, it is said, his teeth. The two regions of felicity,
>   viz., Goloka and Brahmaloka, became his upper and lower lips. The
>   terrible night that succeeds universal destruction, and that
>   transcends the three attributes, became his neck. Having assumed this
>   form endued with the equine head and having diverse things for its
>   diverse limbs, the Lord of the universe disappeared then and there,
>   and proceeded to the nether regions. Having reached those regions, he
>   set himself to high Yoga. Adopting a voice regulated by the rules of
>   the science called Siksha, he began to utter loudly Vedic Mantras. His
>   pronunciation was distinct and reverberated through the air, and was
>   sweet in every respect. The sound of his voice filled the nether
>   region from end to end. Endued with the properties of all the
>   elements, it was productive of great benefits. The two Asuras, making
>   an appointment with the Vedas in respect of the time when they would
>   come back to take them up again, threw them down in the nether region,
>   and ran towards the spot whence those sounds appeared to come.
>   **Meanwhile, O king, the Supreme Lord with the equine head, otherwise
>   called Hari, who was himself in the nether region, took up all the
>   Vedas. Returning to where Brahma was staying, he gave the Vedas unto
>   him. Having restored the Vedas unto Brahma, the Supreme Lord once more
>   returned to his own nature.** The Supreme Lord also established his form
>   with the equine head in the North-Eastern region of the great ocean.
>   Having (in this way) established him who was the abode of the Vedas,
>   he once more became the equine-headed form that he was. The two
>   Danavas Madhu and Kaitabha, not finding the person from whom those
>   sounds proceeded, quickly came back to that spot. They cast their eyes
>   around but beheld that the spot on which they had thrown the Vedas was
>   empty. Those two foremost of mighty Beings, adopting great speed of
>   motion, rose from the nether region. Returning to where the primeval
>   Lotus was that had given them birth, they saw the puissant Being, the
>   original Creator, staying in the form of Aniruddha of fair complexion
>   and endued with a splendour resembling that of the Moon. Of
>   immeasurable prowess, he was under the influence of Yoga-sleep, his
>   body stretched on the waters and occupying a space as vast as itself.
>   Possessed of great effulgence and endued with the attribute of
>   stainless Sattwa, the body of the Supreme Lord lay on the excellent
>   hood of a snake that seemed to emit flames of fire for the
>   resplendence attaching to it. Beholding the Lord thus lying, the two
>   foremost of Danavas roared out a loud laugh. Endued with the
>   attributes of Rajas and Tamas, they said.--'This is that Being of
>   white complexion. He is now lying asleep. Without doubt, this one has
>   brought the Vedas away from the nether region. Whose is he? Whose is
>   he? Who is he? Why is he thus asleep on the hood of a snake: Uttering
>   these words, the two Danavas awakened Hari from his Yoga-slumber. The
>   foremost of Beings, (viz., Narayana), thus awakened, understood that
>   the two Danavas intended to have an encounter with him in battle.
>   Beholding the two foremost of Asuras prepared to do battle with him,
>   he also set his mind to gratify that desire of theirs. Thereupon an
>   encounter took place between those two on one side and Narayana on the
>   other. The Asuras Madhu and Kaitabha were embodiments of the
>   attributes of Rajas and Tamas. Narayana slew them both for gratifying
>   Brahma. He thence came to be called by the name of Madhusudana (slayer
>   of Madhu). Having compassed the destruction of the two Asuras and
>   restored the Vedas to Brahma, the Supreme Being dispelled the grief of
>   Brahma. Aided then by Hari and assisted by the Vedas, Brahma created
>   all the worlds with their mobile and immobile creatures.