# Can a Sanyasi allowed to do Yagnas for dethrone and enthrone kings?

Tags: scripture, sanyasi

Is it valid for a Sanyasi to perform yagnas or any rituals for enthroning a person and to dethrone another person? Do scriptures allow it?

Comment: A sanyasi can not perform yajna, because first thing they do is renounce Agni when they get initiated.

Comment: yagnas or rituals you refer to are done by brahmin priests, not by sadhus.

Comment: You can see my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22679/4732). They are not allowed to perform Vedic rituals.