# Can Sandhyavandanam be performed by Sanyasis?

Tags: scripture, vedic-rituals, sandhyavandanam, sanyasi, sannyasa

Can Sandhyavandanam be performed by Sanyasis?

I am not sure of this topic and there are different answers which state otherwise.

Can someone please clarify who and all can perform Sandhyavandanam and whether the head of matams or peetams (Sanyasis)  should perform Sandhyavandanam?

Comment: If you retain the tags you have added then the more relevant tags (I have added) won't find the space (more than 5 tags is not allowed)

Comment: Also see -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17227/4732

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, Sanyasis cannot perform Sandhyavandanam? I think I read about Kanchi Periyavar performing Sandhyavandana? Is it true that the heads of Shankara Peetams or any other Hindu Peetams should not perform Sandhyavandanam?

Comment: Kanchi Periyava and Sannyasis like him obviously knows much better than us .. But we can show by quoting from the Sannyasa Upanishads that a Sannyasi has to abandon all rituals including Sandhyavandanam. But this position might be contradicted by other scriptures. So, I am not entirely sure about it. Some Sannyasis for example remove their sacred threads while some others don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the kind of Sannyasi.

Vishishtadvaitin Sannyasis do perform Sandhyavandana. (They sport the Yajnopavita and the shikhA as well).

Sources:

1. Yatidharmasamuccaya of Yadavaprakasa,
2. Srivaishnava Sadachara Nirnaya of Srimad Narayana Yatindra Mahadesika

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer. I will give a quote from Sri Ramakrishna on Sandhya.

> Sri Ramakrishna said: **"When, hearing the name of Hari or Rama once,
> you shed tears and your hair stands on end, then you may know for
> certain that you do not have to perform such devotions as the sandhya
> any more. Then only will you have a right to renounce rituals; or
> rather, rituals will drop away of themselves.** Then it will be enough
> it you repeat only the name of Rama or Hari, or even simply Om."
> Continuing, he said, **"The sandhya merges in the Gayatri, and the
> Gayatri merges in Om."**

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, chapter 1, Master and Disciple**

It seems from the above passage that a sanyasi will not have to perform such rituals as he makes spiritual progress.

Comment: one cannot make a conscious decision to renounce sandhya. it must be involuntary, like the way one's heart beats without conscious decision making. maybe 10 people out of a crore in a 100 years reach this stage. so the rule for people is to continue karma until it falls off - the same way you don't consciously sleep - you just fall asleep.