# What do we mean by pure consciousness when we address Brahman?

Tags: brahman, advaita, consciousness

After going through so many online articles i'm still not sure what exactly is Brahman as per advaita. Yes it can't be grasped by our limited senses but those who did describe "IT" has said the following-

**Some say, Brahman is everything.**
Does this mean, even non living objects like rocks, mountains, rivers, chairs, cars, are they all Brahman?

**Some say, Brahman is the atman inside us (living beings) and those who realize their own soul to be the eternal aspect, attain moksha.**
Does this mean, advaitists are atheists, since they don't consider a higher creator entity and consider their own soul to be the only object of realization ? ... If there's no God as per advaita but only embodied atmas as Brahman, then does this mean, we atmas as a whole created galaxies, solar systems, planets etc. before entering into gross flesh bodies?

**And finally, there are advaitists, who say Brahman is pure consciousness.** Now i'm going to ask who's consciousness? Individual consciousness or universal consciousness? And what is meant by universal consciousness.

Please explain these three in a simplified manner. To me duality makes more sense, but hinduist monism aka advaita is a lot more hard to grasp, especially if you're not a hindu.

Comment: Advaita, Dvaita and Vishishtadvaita are 3 main schools of thought with different philosophies. Dualist - Dvaita makes more sense because that's what we perceive and that's what the reality is, well to a certain extent. Advaita says all this is an illusion, and the only truth is Brahman (God consciousness), which remains concealed due to that illusion. Well to me Advaita makes more sense, IMO. "IMO" is what 6 schools of Vedanta are based. Every teacher had their own opinion.

Comment: Hindu concept of God is not just a creator. Consciousness manifests everything as a universal vibration, just as we think in our minds. Consider thinking of the universe. In your mental space, you've created a universe replica. This is the same as the Supreme Consciousness manifesting a universe, which is the material universe in which we live. Brahman is the creator, in the sense that when Brahman is affected by the 3 modes of nature, (purity, passion, ignorance), it assumes 3 cosmic roles (creation, maintenance and destruction). This form is known as Ishvara. Ishvara is what you mean by God.

Comment: Rather Ishvara is what non-Hindus map to their belief of God. But Ishvara is still a consciousness, which thrives on being conscious of itself. That consciousness when traced beyond Ishvara is pure Brahman. Ishvara mode is called Saguna Brahman (sa - with, guna - attribute) whereas pure Brahman is Nirguna (nir - without).

Comment: The purest form of Saguna Brahman is generally considered to be Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva, the famous Trinity, carrying out the 3 cosmic roles as I mentioned.

Comment: You've mentioned "some say Brahman is everything", "Brahman is the atman inside us (living beings)" and "finally there are advaitists....", all separately. In reality Advaitists themselves say that Brahman is everything. Nothing is independent of Brahman. And Advaitists also say that Brahman is the Atman inside us. I have explained to you in the Samkhya post, how Jiva = Purusha. Nothing derives its existence without Brahman, because "Existence" is a primary attribute of Brahman. Sat-Chid-Ananda = Existence-sentience-bliss. -> True description of Brahman.

Comment: Take a look at three levels of reality explained [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12347/277).

Comment: @ Arkaprabha, Thanks for the nice explanation but i'm still having a hard time understanding a few things ...1) You said that when Brahman is affected by 3 modes of nature, it assumes the roles of trinity. But advaita says, Brahman is changeless and eternal. If it is changeless, then how can it be affected by  prakriti? Changeless Brahman means a static and dormant Brahman. Isn't it?

Comment: ... 2) Being conscious of , means to be aware of... So if Nirguna Brahm is poorna or complete and has no need to know or create anything , then what exactly it became conscious or aware of in the first place?

Comment: @CrimsonUniverse .. Brahman is changeless in the fact that Brahman is injected into Prakriti, but it is due to Maya (Prakriti) that Brahman is deluded. However the essence of Brahman, its essential nature is unaffected. Everything ultimately roots down to Brahman, and nothing else. Nothing derives its existence apart from Brahman.

Comment: The second answer cannot be answered by me, as I am not someone who has had direct experience of this.  :)   .. Sorry mate.. I am not helpful here. I have put my faith in Scriptures and Gurus' words.

Comment: @ Uday krishna, There's a huge difference between God existing in an object and God IS that object ... The former is , if i'm not wrong, pan-en-theism, which says God pervades and interpenetrates it's creation and is also beyond it, which makes more sense to me. While the latter is pantheism , which says everything is God and there's no difference between reality and divinity. So when we say God exists in me, you, or in the pillar, it is pan-en-theism, since God pervades everything, but God IMO, doesn't actually becomes that thing. If im God then i could have easily created the universe :)

Comment: For further/excessive discussion, use chat room instead.

Answer (score 1):

**[Some say, Brahman is everything. Does this mean, even non living objects like rocks, mountains, rivers, chairs, cars, are they all Brahman?]**

This claim cannot be debated. Either one has experienced it and knows or one doesn't know.

There is this Gita verse that says that all is Brahman.

> To one of the above description, **the ladle with which the offering is
>   made and the oblations are Brahman; and the sacrificial rites (which
>   is Brahman) is performed by the sacrifice who is Brahman, in the fire
>   which too is Brahman. He who is thus absorbed in work as Brahman**,
>   attains to Brahman alone.

*Gita 4.24*

Then there is a record of Swami Vivekananda (Narendra) directly experiencing that state.

> During his second visit, about a month later, suddenly, at the touch
>   of the Master, Narendra felt overwhelmed and saw the walls of the room
>   and everything around him whirling and vanishing. "What are you doing
>   to me?" he cried in terror. "I have my father and mother at home." He
>   saw his own ego and the whole universe almost swallowed in a nameless
>   void. With a laugh the Master easily restored him. Narendra thought he
>   might have been hypnotized, but he could not understand how a
>   monomaniac could cast a spell over the mind of a strong person like
>   himself. He returned home more confused than ever, resolved to be
>   henceforth on his guard before this strange man.
>
> But during his third visit Narendra fared no better. This time, at the
>   Master's touch, he lost consciousness entirely. While he was still in
>   that state, Sri Ramakrishna questioned him concerning his spiritual
>   antecedents and whereabouts, his mission in this world, and the
>   duration of his mortal life. The answers confirmed what the Master
>   himself had known and inferred. Among other things, he came to know
>   that Narendra was a sage who had already attained perfection, and that
>   the day he learnt his real nature he would give up his body in yoga,
>   by an act of will.
>
> A few more meetings completely removed from Narendra's mind the last
>   traces of the notion that Sri Ramakrishna might be a monomaniac or
>   wily hypnotist. His integrity, purity, renunciation, and unselfishness
>   were beyond question. But Narendra could not accept a man, an
>   imperfect mortal, as his guru. As a member of the Brahmo Samaj, he
>   could not believe that a human intermediary was necessary between man
>   and God. Moreover, he openly laughed at Sri Ramakrishna's visions as
>   hallucinations. Yet in the secret chamber of his heart he bore a great
>   love for the Master.
>
> Sri Ramakrishna was grateful to the Divine Mother for sending him one
>   who doubted his own realizations. Often he asked Narendra to test him
>   as the money-changers test their coins. He laughed at Narendra's
>   biting criticism of his spiritual experiences and samadhi. When at
>   times Narendra's sharp words distressed him, the Divine Mother Herself
>   would console him, saying: "Why do you listen to him? In a few days he
>   will believe your every word." He could hardly bear Narendra's
>   absences. Often he would weep bitterly for the sight of him. Sometimes
>   Narendra would find the Master's love embarrassing; and one day he
>   sharply scolded him, warning him that such infatuation would soon draw
>   him down to the level of its object. The Master was distressed and
>   prayed to the Divine Mother. Then he said to Narendra: "You rogue, I
>   won't listen to you any more. Mother says that I love you because I
>   see God in you, and the day I no longer see God in you I shall not be
>   able to bear even the sight of you."
>
> The Master wanted to train Narendra in the teachings of the
>   non-dualistic Vedanta philosophy. But Narendra, because of his Brahmo
>   upbringing, considered it wholly blasphemous to look on man as one
>   with his Creator. One day at the temple garden he laughingly said to a
>   friend: "How silly! This jug is God! This cup is God! Whatever we see
>   is God! And we too are God! Nothing could be more absurd." Sri
>   Ramakrishna came out of his room and gently touched him. **Spellbound,
>   he immediately perceived that everything in the world was indeed God.
>   A new universe opened around him. Returning home in a dazed state, he
>   found there too that the food, the plate, the eater himself, the
>   people around him, were all God. When he walked in the street, he saw
>   that the cabs, the horses, the streams of people, the buildings, were
>   all Brahman. He could hardly go about his day's business. His parents
>   became anxious about him and thought him ill. And when the intensity
>   of the experience abated a little, he saw the world as a dream.
>   Walking in the public square, he would strike his head against the
>   iron railings to know whether they were real. It took him a number of
>   days to recover his normal self.** He had a foretaste of the great
>   experiences yet to come and realized that the words of the Vedanta
>   were true.

*The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna translated by Swami Nikhilananda,, Introduction, Narendra*

**[Some say, Brahman is the atman inside us (living beings) and those who realize their own soul to be the eternal aspect, attain moksha. Does this mean, advaitists are atheists, since they don't consider a higher creator entity and consider their own soul to be the only object of realization ? ... If there's no God as per advaita but only embodied atmas as Brahman, then does this mean, we atmas as a whole created galaxies, solar systems, planets etc. before entering into gross flesh bodies?]**

No, it does not mean advaitists are atheists. It means they are non-theists. What does this mean?

> Do you know what I mean? Think of Brahman, Existence-Knowledge-Bliss
>   Absolute, as a shoreless ocean. Through the cooling influence as it
>   were, of the bhakta's love, the water has frozen at places into blocks
>   of ice. In other words, God now and then assumes various forms for His
>   lovers and reveals Himself to them as a Person. But with the rising of
>   the sun of knowledge, the blocks of ice melt. Then one doesn't feel
>   any more that God is a Person, nor does one see God's forms. What He
>   is cannot be described. Who will describe Him? He who would do so
>   disappears. He cannot find his 'I' anymore.

*The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, The Master with Brahmo Devotees (I), October 28, 1882*

The above passage is best understood if you think of the Earth and its frozen poles but minus its lands. Theism deals with the realm of icebergs floating in the Northern and Southern oceans. Only in the frozen areas can one talk of the universe and its living beings and different forms of God. Different theistic systems claim different icebergs to be the Supreme Being. Advaitists are those who want to be in the iceberg free open ocean. No concept of form exists in this realm. There is only formless water everywhere. There is no individual ego either. Thus there is no way one can have a creator God in this realm.

**[And finally, there are advaitists, who say Brahman is pure consciousness. Now i'm going to ask who's consciousness? Individual consciousness or universal consciousness? And what is meant by universal consciousness.]**

There is no other person when one reaches the state of Nirguna Brahman. In that state Brahman is all.

> If one analyzes oneself, one doesn't find any such thing as 'I'. Take
>   an onion, for instance. First of all peel off the red outer skin; then
>   you find thick white skins. Peel these off one after the other, and
>   you won't find anything inside.
>
> In that state a man no longer finds the existence of his ego. And who
>   is there left to seek it? Who can describe how he feels in that state
>   - in his own Pure Consciousness - about the real nature of Brahman?
>
> **There is a sign of Perfect Knowledge. Man becomes silent when It is
>   attained. Then the 'I', which may be likened to the salt doll, melts
>   in the ocean of Existence-Knowledge-Bliss Absolute and becomes one
>   with It. Not the slightest distinction is left**.

*The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, The Master with Brahmo Devotees (I), October 28, 1882*

The statement that Brahman is pure consciousness is only an analogy. Since we see conscious beings and Brahman is the source of all consciousness  it must be pure consciousness. Actually nothing can be said about Brahman.

> "What Brahman is cannot be described. All things in the world - the
>   Vedas, the Puranas, the Tantras, the six systems of philosophy - have
>   been defiled, like food that has been touched by the tongue. Only one
>   thing has not been defiled in this way, and that is Brahman. **No one
>   has ever been able to say what Brahman is.Brahman is beyond word and
>   thought.** It is said in the Vedas that Brahman is of the nature of
>   Bliss. It is Satchidananda. **In Samadhi one attains the knowledge of
>   Brahman - one realizes Brahman. In that state reasoning stops
>   altogether, and man becomes mute. He has no power to describe the
>   nature of Brahman."**

*The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Visit to Vidyasagar, August 5, 1882*

> The Upanishad also declares Brahman to be Consciousness alone. The
>   Upanishad also says that Brahman is pure consciousness, devoid of
>   other aspects contrary to this, and without any distinguishing
>   features, as in, “As a lump of salt is without interior or exterior,
>   entire, and purely saline in taste, even so is the Self without
>   interior or exterior, entire, and pure Intelligence alone”
>   (Brhadaranyaka Upanishad IV.v.13), which means that the Self has no
>   internal or external aspect apart from pure consciousness, Its nature
>   being mere impartite consciousness without any interstices. Just as a
>   lump of salt has the saline taste alone both inside and outside, and
>   no other taste, so also is this Self.

*Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya III.ii.16*

> Moreover, the Vedas reveal this; likewise this is mentioned in the
>   Smritis also.Moreover, the Vedas reveal through a negation of other
>   aspects that Brahman has no distinguishing feature, as for instance
>   in, “Now therefore the description (of Brahman): ‘Not this, not this’”
>   (Brhadaranyaka Upanishad II.iii.6), “That (Brahman) is surely
>   different from the known; and, again, It is above the unknown” (Kena
>   Upanishad I.4), “That Bliss of Brahman, failing to reach which, words
>   turn back along with the mind” (Taittiriya Upanishad II.ix.1), and so
>   on. **And it is also known from the Vedic texts that Badhva being asked
>   by Baskali, replied merely by not uttering a word, as stated in, “He
>   (Baskali) said, ‘Teach me Brahman, sir.’ He (Badhva) became silent.
>   When the question was repeated a second and a third time he said, ‘I
>   have already spoken, but you cannot comprehend. That Self is
>   Quiescence’ “.** Similarly in the Smritis, the instruction is given
>   through a negation of other things, as in, “I shall tell you of that
>   which is to be known and by knowing which one attains immortality. The
>   supreme Brahman is without any beginning. It can neither be called
>   gross (visible) nor fine (invisible)” (Gita XIII.12), and so on.
>   Similarly the Smriti mentions how Narayana in His cosmic form said to
>   Narada, “O Narada, that you see me as possessed of all the (five
>   divine) qualities of all elements, is only because of My Maya, called
>   up by Myself. For else you should not understand Me thus.”

*Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya III.ii.17*

Brahman defeats all attempt to describe It and hence the silence.

Comment: Ramakrishna Paramahansa had indeed given amazing examples as metaphors to philosophical concepts. Nice answer.

Comment: @ Pradip Gangopadhyay , You've mentioned in your post that Vivekananda found it absurd that the jar is God, the cup is God etc. But wasn't he a Brahmo? As far as i know, Brahmoism is all about realizing Brahman and like advaitists they too believe that everything is God, then why Vivekananda being a Brahmo couldn't accept that all is God?

Comment: @Pradip, Ok so let me try and describe Brahman in my own words, even though such a description is never going to do justice. I see Brahman like the endless akasha or the great cosmic spirit that pervades everything, and part of it upon contact with maya becomes the non living objects & part of it becomes the embodied jeevas. (Is it ok to call Nirguna Brahm a great cosmic spirit or calling it a spirit makes it saguna?) ... And what exactly happens after videha mukti? Does the soul merges with Brahmajyoti as Prabhupada claims OR the soul simply disintegrates, as in "poof" in the endless akasha?

Comment: @CrimsonUniverse, the answer to your first comment is that Brahmos do not believe everything is God. They believe like the Christians that Brahman is the Father of all and not He is all. This is the reason Vivekananda initially denounced advaita thought as blasphemy.

Comment: @CrimsonUniverse, Yes, you can think of Nirguna Brahman as endless akasha. Only thing you should remember is that anything that humans think of It is an approximation.You can call It a spirit if you want. You are asking about the fate of someone who attains advaita mukti. The scriptural texts say that such a person becomes Brahman. No one who has not experienced it can know what exactly it is. There is no point in speculating about such an esoteric subject.

Comment: @Pradip, Hmmm... You think Brahmoism is still active today in India? I would love to do more research on it, like their beliefs, practices etc. Could you recommend me books or articles, like for beginners with simple English. Thnx.

Comment: @Pradip, Also when the Buddhists say that they don't believe in a soul or atman (anatta) and instead believes that it's the consciousness that reincarnates... are they still correct as per advaita? Since according to advaita it's the same thing ... Atman = Brahman = Consciousness ... So could it be that the Buddhists are using a different term to explain the same thing? ... In the Atman wikipedia page , under etymology , it's mentioned that atman is different than consciousness. I'm a little confused here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80tman_(Hinduism)

Comment: @Crimson, Brahmoism has at present a few thousand followers. It is essentially unitarian Christianity with a thin layer of Upanishad's Brahman. I don't know of any book or article on Brahmoism.

Comment: @Crimson, Buddhists do not accept the existence of Self. Buddhist rebirth probably means that the karma of person A is inherited by person B with no link between A or B. Don't depend on wikipedia for information.

Comment: @ Pradip, umm ok... I need to know one more thing. It's about the causal body. I was going through an article on an advaitic website where it was mentioned that the causal body doesn't reincarnate but only the subtle body does. Is it true? If so, then where does the causal body goes after death of the gross body? ... Also does each of us individual jeevas possess separate causal bodies? The article said that there's no separate causal bodies in each of us, but the maya (of the cosmic wordly level) is known as causal body (in the individual level). What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: The causal body keeps our karmic record witnessed by the Atman and the sense organs. It is called causal body since the record kept in it causes rebirth of the individual. The above information suggests that the causal body is unique to each individual and also reincarnates. Otherwise no reincarnation is possible.

Comment: Here's an excerpt from an article by S.S.Raghavachar (1962), which describes the causal body as ignorance / avidya. (as per advaita). Thought you would be interested in it ... ""In deep-sleep (sushupti) state, the body of the self is said to be causal, meaning that it is the seed of the subtle and the gross bodies and that it is the pure unactualised potentiality of the body. It consists of the original Nescience (ignorance) from which spring the phenomenal manifestations of the dream and waking worlds. This nescience covers and does not annihilate the self-effulgence of the Atman"".

Comment: A correction to my comment on the reincarnation of the causal body. The causal body accompanies the subtle body both after death and after rebirth. According to the Advaita school the causal body does not reincarnate during the rebirth process since avidya maya being power of Ishvara is never born.

Comment: And then there's the belief of the Yoga school of philosophy , that the causal body is a part of anandamaya kosha which is luminous and not darkness or ignorance as advaita says. This anandamaya or causal body as per yoga is bliss, and realization of this is akin to self realization ... I mean each school has their own theories/beliefs which differs from each other. Wonder what the truth is. Guess we will never know 

Comment: Even advaita says that the causal body is anandamya kosha. The ananda or bliss experienced is the bliss of the Atman.

Comment: But how can ignorance = causal body be bliss? ... I've read somewhere that the reflection of the actual atman falls on the causal body first, and due to this in many sects of vedanta, the causal body which recieves the reflection of the atman, is erronously considered by the meditator  as the atman itself. But as per shankara , the meditator should go beyond anandamaya kosha or causal body and reach the ultimate truth ,that is the Atman. The anandamaya kosha or causal body according to Shankara is a product of maya and is left behind when the atman attains videha mukti.

Comment: You are conflating the function of the thin layer of avidya maya (also called causal body and anadamaya kosha) with the experience of Yogis. The avidya maya shakti or the causal body veils the Atman from the Jiva and projects the universe and its living beings thus allowing us the human experience. If we knew we are Atman we will not have the human experience. Yogis experience infinite bliss when drilling through the causal body and hence it is called anandmaya kosha. The bliss experienced is really the bliss of the Atman and it is experienced because the causal body  layer is very thin.