# Is the universe a manifestation of one's own soul?

Tags: scripture, advaita, atma

We are living in a universe and each one may have different interpretations towards the universe and all the aspects of the universe.

Is the universe (we are living in) is a manifestation of our own soul?

If it is a manifestation of one's own soul, then how do many souls have same manifestation? Is it due to overlapping of some aspect of soul (like karma)?

Or does the soul contain the universe?

Comment: True and not true

Comment: It is like a classroom where the soul is a student, it can't destroy the school and can affect it, depending on it's will how big or small the change it wants to create.

Comment: Your question is unclear as you use the term 'soul'. Do you mean the Atman which is synonymous with Brahman? Or do you mean the individual jiva. Depending upon your meaning it can lead to different answers to your question.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda The soul of Jiva.

Comment: True for (Soul as paramatma as one supersoul residing hearts of all being) and Not true for (Another as jivatma residing in  hearts of each being as unique to that being) there is 2 souls in each chetana dvsuparana in one of the upaishad

Answer (score 1):

True for (Soul as paramatma as one supersoul residing in hearts of all being) and Not true for (Another as jivatma residing in hearts of each being as unique to that being) there are 2 souls in each living being (even tough there can be many jivas in the same body but one primary jiva is the enjoyer of fruits) i.e. chetana as described as dvsuparana in

> > Mandukya Upanishad 3.1:1
>
> द्वा सुपर्णा सयुजा सखाया समानं वृक्षं परिषस्वजाते।
> तयोरन्य: पिप्पलं स्वाद्वत्त्यनश्नन्नन्यो अभिचाकशीति॥
> समाने वृक्षे पुरुषों निमग्नोऽनाशया शोचति मुह्यमान:।
> जुष्टं यदा पश्यत्यन्यमीशमस्य महिमानमिति वीतशोक:॥
> यदा पश्य: पश्यते रुक्मवर्णं कर्तारमीशं पुरुषं ब्रह्मयोनिम्।
> तदा विद्वान्पुण्यपापे विधूय निरंजन: परमं साम्यमुपैति॥
>
> > 

> Dwa Suparna Sayuja Sakhaya Samanam Vriksam Pariswajate
> Tayor anyah pippalam swadu atti, anashnan anyo abhijakashiti.
>
> > - Mundaka Upanishad 3.1:1

> Samane vrikshe purusho nimagno 'nishaya shocati muhyamanah
> Jushtam yada pashyati anyam isham asya mahimanam iti vita-shokah

> > Mundaka Upanishad 3.1:2

> Yada pashyah pashyate rukma-varnam kartaram isham purusham brahma-yonim
> Tada vidvan punya-pape vidhuya niranjanah paramam samyam upaiti -

> > Mundaka >Upanishad 3.1:3

Meaning in English:

> > Two birds living together, each the friend of the other, perch upon the same tree

> > Of these two, one eats the fruits of the tree, but the other simply looks on without eating.

> > Although the two birds are on the same tree, the eating bird is fully engrossed with anxiety and moroseness.

> > If in some way or other he turns his face to his friend who is the Lord, at once the suffering bird becomes free of all anxieties

> > One who sees the golden colored bird, the Lord, the actor, who is the source of the Supreme Brahman, is liberated.

> > Such a person becomes wise. He becomes free of both pious and sinful karmic reactions. He becomes pure. He attains a spiritual form like that of the Lord >>Himself.

According to the above Universe is created by Paramatma and is the manifestation of Paramatma, The context of self(Atman varies according to interperation of the context) whenever some statement like the below answer says that universe is all self.. means universe is premeated with ataman(Supreme self i.e. Bhagavan in all) it doesnt mean Jiva or soul is premeated with all, then this should be true, when one drinks it should satisfy other person thirst. it was shown by Lord krishna alone in mahabharata where he takes one leaf of akshaya patra and consumes, saying satisfied. Sage Durvas stomach was full.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the whole universe is manifestation of Self alone.

> He who is devoted to the path of action, whose mind is it pure, who
> has conered the self, who has subdued his senses and who realizes **his
> Self as the Self in all beings**, though acting, is not tainted.(BG 5.7)
>
> It moves, it is motionless. It is distant, it is near. It is within
> all, it is without all this. Who sees everything in his Atman and his
> Atman in everything, by that he feels no revulsion.(Isa Up 5-6)
>
> Now that light which shines above this heaven, higher than all, higher
> than everything, in the highest world, beyond which there are no other
> worlds, that is the same light which is within man.(Chandogya
> Upanishad 3.13.7)
>
> This is my Soul in the innermost heart, greater than the earth,
> greater than the aerial space, greater than these worlds. This Soul,
> this Self of mine is that Brahman.(Chandogya Upanishad 3.14.3-4)
>
> And when he becomes a god, as it were, or a king, as it were, or
> thinks, **‘This universe is myself, who am all,’ that is his highest
> state**.(Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 4.3.20)

In Upadesha Sahasri verse 6, Shankaracharya says

> He should first of all teach the Sruti texts establishing the oneness
> of the Self with Brahman such as, " My (Chan Up 6.2.1) child, in the
> beginning it (the universe) was Existence only, one alone without a
> second," "Where (Chan Up 7.24.1) one sees nothing else," "All (Chan Up
> 7.25.2) this is but the Self", " In (Ai Up 1.1.1) the beginning all this was but the one Self " and " All (Chan Up 3.14.1) this is verily
> Brahman".

Comment: Excellent answer. As the universe is Self, it is not unreal or asat. This is the correct understanding of Advaita.

Comment: Thankyou sir @GIRIBLR

Comment: @GIRIBLR so you are contradicting yourself, because self is real, than universe is real according to advaita that is what i inferred from your statment. But advaita says clearly that universal is unreal jagath mithya.. that is foundation of the philosophy of Advaita. Now According Posulate of Advaita since Universe is Unreal than self is also unreal right.. The above conculsion is for dvaita alone.world is real and self is real

Comment: @PrasannaR You are misunderstanding Advaitha. Please go through these links
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44489/19211
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35926/19211
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13596/19211
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19935/19211

Comment: @PrasannaR Shankaracharya while refuting Buddhists says "The very fact that the Bauddhas say that the internal cognition appears ‘as something external’ shows that the external world is real. If it were not real, the comparison ‘like something external’ would be meaningless. No one says that Devadatta is like the son of a barren woman."(Bramha Sutra 2.2.28)

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru that is what we say in dvaita, when shankara refutes buddhist in brahma sutra he takes dualist view saying the world is real and jiva is also real.. in his brahma sutra bhasya. he contradicts himself when he tries derieve advaita siddanta in other places

Comment: Please study the links I sent @PrasannaR

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Dk4EIe-qyk
@PrasannaR Hear this lecture also

Comment: ayyo pavvamae that is what one seein the above video link, blue sky, golden ring anology  is not apt defining soul and paramatma.. i had refuted already, blue sky, colourles sky retains the primary property of vastness, similarly Golden ring and Golden retains their primary properties because of which what they are called they are. like white elephant and brown elephant. an elephat is elephant.. right.. now elephant and ant are same will you accept that.. because the primary properties are not .. when doing soul and paramatma comparision its not even elephant and ant anology be applied.

Comment: @PrasannaR https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62758.html

Comment: What does Shankara say? He says: (1) Brahman is real; (2) the universe is a mithya; (3) Brahman is the universe. He does not stop at the second statement but continues to supplement it with the third. What does it signify? The Universe is conceived to be apart from Brahman and that perception is wrong ...Ramana Maharshi Talk 315. I think Sethu Sir has answered the rest.